# How should I store attributes in a many to many relation in sails.js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sails.js, waterline

I currently created the following tables in my sails project, I have a table named "Users" and a table named "Attendance". These tables are stored in a MySQL database.

Each User can be part of many Attendances and each Attendance can have many users.

This is achieved with the following code:

Attendance model:

```
attributes: {

    attendees: {
        collection: 'user',
        via: 'attendancelist',
        dominant: true
}
```

User model:

```
attributes{

    attendancelist: {
       collection: 'attendance',
       via: 'attendees'
    }
}
```

This will create a table named: attendence_attendees__user_attendancelist

Now I would like the store the "Status" of each User. The status will be a bool describing if the user on the Attendance was present or not.

I would like to store the status of each user in the "attendence_attendees__user_attendancelist" table.

Is this possible or is there a better way to store the status ?

I managed to create a custom associative table but now sails no longer adds data to the associative table. I use the following code:

```
//Attendance model
attributes: {

    attendees: {
        collection: 'user',
        via: 'attendancelist',
        through: 'userattendance'
}

//User model
attributes{

    attendancelists: {
       collection: 'attendance',
       via: 'attendees',
       through: 'userattendance'
    }
}

//Userattendance model
attributes:{

    attendancelist: {
        model: 'attendance',
        foreignKey: true,
        columnName: 'attendance_id'
    },

    attendees: {
        model: 'user',
        foreignKey: true,
        columnName: 'user_id'
    },

    status: {
        type: 'boolean',
        defaultsTo: false
    }

}

//controller method to add data:
getGroupAttendees: function(req, res){
    Group.findOne({id: req.param('groupID')})
        .populateAll()
        .exec(function getGroup(err, group){
            if(err) return res.negotiate(err);
            if(!groep) return res.json(401, {err:'group not found'});
            var users = [];
            group.attendees.forEach(function(user){
                users.push(_.pick(user, ['id']));
            })

            var attendancelistOBJ = {
                planning: 1,
                attendees: users
            }
            Attendance.create(attendancelistOBJ, function agendaCreated(err, lijst){
        
                    if(err) return res.negotiate(err);
                    lijst.save(function(err, lst){
                        if(err) return next(err);
                        return  res.json(attendancelistOBJ.attendees);
                    });
            
            });
        })
}
```

The above controller method used to work perfectly with the auto generated associative table, but with the custom one it no longer adds users and lists to the table.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I follow completely but if you have a many-to-many relationship than you will need an associative table that joins the two tables together and the primary key in that table is a composite key from both the primary keys in the `User` and `Attendance` tables. Maybe you could store your status in that associative table.

Does that make sense, and/or help?

Comment: I do have an associative table, It is automatically generated by waterline.
It is the "attendence_attendees__user_attendancelist" table mentioned above. I want to add a column in this table, but I do not know how to alter this table in Sails.